# java swing jtable screen location of cell renderer component

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, jcheckbox

I'm new to swing and I faced my first serious problem, here goes:

I have a JPanel with JTable and lots of checkboxes below the table. I'm trying to align the checkboxes below the table with checkbox located in the first table column. The problem is - this has to be done when model data changes.

Immediatly after the fireTableDataChanged() gets triggered in JTable there is no way to get the screen location of its custom cell renderer component (which in my case is JCheckBox).
As far as I understand this happens because JTable gets redrawn asynchronously. Whenever I try to get the location the IllegalComponentStateException gets thrown.

Any ideas on this are highly appreciated.

Comment: So lets say you succeed in getting your checkbox aligned with the checkbox in the table ... what should happen if the user changes the column width of your table column, hence changing the location of the jtable checkbox ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the important thing is they will be aligned when the user sees the table for the first time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: QDS: use another JTable below the first one. Set  setTableHeader(null)', 'showHorizontalLines(false)', 'showVerticalLines(false)' on it. This way it will look like a panel and Swing will take care of the alignment for you. You could also probably use the same ColumnModel on both tables, so when the user resizes a column on the first table, it will also get resized in the 2nd. Not sure about that though.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, Nikola but it looks more like a hack.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do it manually. You should use the appropriate layoutManager. Check this link for the different Layouts:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: I don't see how layout managers can help since I have components below the table. Checkbox inside the table cell has a JCheckBox.CENTER alignment. And I don't want to hardcode their inset values.

Comment: LAyout Managers automatically fixes all problems related to visual such as alignment and they handle page resize, component resize, ...

Comment: By using LayoutManager, you would **NEVER** change insets

Comment: No, I'm using GridBagLayout everywhere in my app and still don't see how layout managers can help me solve my problem. The only possible way is to somehow get the x of the renderer component inside the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get screen location of row and column.

`Rectangle rect= cartTable.getCellRect(row,column,true);
    //cartTable-Jtable object name
    int x=Double.valueOf(rect.getX()).intValue();
    int y=Double.valueOf(rect.getY()).intValue();`